# how to create an list of a specific type but empty

Tags: python, object

How to create a list of a specific type of object but empty? Is it possible? I want to create an array of objects (the type is called Ghosts) which later will contain different types that inherit from that one class called Ghosts. It's all very simple in C++ but i'm not sure how to do that in python. I tried something like this:

```
self.arrayOfGhosts = [[Ghost() for x in xrange(100)] for x in xrange(100)]
```

but it's already initialised by objects, and I don't need it, is there a way to initialise it by 0 but have an list of type Ghost?

As you see I'm very new to python. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Got to stop trying to write c? code in python mate. As long as the thingy in the list implements the method you are calling on it, it will work. No need to try and impose static typing on it.

Comment: I'm more of a C programmer, I just have to write that one project in python and don't even have much time to learn.

Comment: Aye, been there mate, fastest way to trip up though is to write in one language and then translate you end up in the J'habite une rouge maison scenario...

Comment: I have no idea what you just said to me about that "rouge maison":P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are lists, not arrays. Python is a duck-typed language. Lists are heterogenously-typed anyway. For example. your list can contain an `int`, followed by `str`, followed by `list`, or whatever suits your fancy. You cannot restrict the type with stock classes, and that's against the philosophy of the language.

Just create an empty list, and add later.

```
self.arrayOfGhosts = []
```

Two-dimensional lists are simple. Just nest lists.

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
l[0]  # [1, 2, 3]
l[1][2]  # 6
```

If you really want placeholders, just do something like the following.

```
[[None] * 100 for i in range(100)]
```

Python doesn't have arrays, unless you mean `array.array`, which is for C-ish types anyways. Arrays are the wrong level of abstraction in Python most of the time.

P.S. If you're using `xrange`, then you must be using Python 2. Unless you need very specific libraries, please stop, and use Python 3. [See why](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).

P.P.S. You initialize with `NULL`, not `0` in C++. Never use `0` to mean `NULL`.

P.P.P.S. See [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the canonical Python style guide.

Comment: ok, but I still want to have two dimensional list as I did, is it possible?

Comment: "[[None] * 100] * 100" - it doesn't work, I have the same list copied 100 times

Comment: `None`, compared by reference to another `None` is always true. If it's a **placeholder**, it doesn't matter, whether you compare by equality or identity. If you want to put semi-initialized ghosts (as in not all code to initialize to a valid stat) in there, then you must use list comprehensions.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly (it's nothing to do with the `None`)

Comment: @johrsharpe: Oops. Right. Thanks. I don't usually do 2d lists. Fixing. Dealt with the sort of bug before, but only in one dimension.

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe and pilona, you helped me :)

Comment: @user3623738: Consider upvoting what was useful, comments included.

Comment: ' philosophy of the language '. Tis truely a phase fit for entry in to the Orwellian book of nightmare

Comment: @FireInTheSky, why? And how is that productive? Languages have a design philosophy, and a way they are expected to be used, along with the rest of the ecosystem. It's expected to be consistent, not surprising every once in a while, which increases the likelihood of bugs.

Answer (score 10):

Python is a dynamic language so there is no concept of `array of type`.
You create an empty generic list with:

```
self.arrayOfGhosts = []
```

You don't care about the capacity of the list as it's dynamically allocated as well.
It's up to you to fill it with as many `Ghost` instances as you wish with:

```
self.arrayOfGhosts.append(Ghost())
```

**The above is really enough, however:**
If you really want to enforce this list to accept only `Ghost` and inheriting classes instances, you can create a custom list type like this:

```
class GhostList(list):

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        """Override initializer which can accept iterable"""
        super(GhostList, self).__init__()
        if iterable:
            for item in iterable:
                self.append(item)

    def append(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, Ghost):
            super(GhostList, self).append(item)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Ghosts allowed only')

    def insert(self, index, item):
        if isinstance(item, Ghost):
            super(GhostList, self).insert(index, item)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Ghosts allowed only')

    def __add__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, Ghost):
            super(GhostList, self).__add__(item)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Ghosts allowed only')

    def __iadd__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, Ghost):
            super(GhostList, self).__iadd__(item)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Ghosts allowed only')
```

Then for two-dimensional list you use this class like:

```
self.arrayOfGhosts = []
self.arrayOfGhosts.append(GhostList())
self.arrayOfGhosts[0].append(Ghost())
```

Comment: To cover all use cases, also add `.insert`, `.__add__` (operator `+`), and `.__iadd__` (operator `+=`), iff needed.

Comment: This is akin to a cannon being used to punch holes in paper.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid see the first part of the answer which clearly says it's not required. The second part is just a proof that to some extent type enforcing is possible in Python.

Comment: By the way, `isinstance` is rarely the answer in Python. See [LYBL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I'm familiar with the linked page and LYBL specifically. I know that it's better to ask for forgiveness than for permission. However in this case you can't reject object which is not a Ghost or it's descendant without checking what it is.

Comment: I'm saying this is an anti-pattern in Python - just the fact that a container is "restricted" is very limited in Python, and even then for a very core reason (hashable types for dict keys, for example). This will work but it is not very Pythonic. Rather than "writing C in Python", it would be better to explain how things are done in Python, Pythonically (yes I made that up).

Comment: OK. Again. I don't see any practical reason to create such restricted container in Python. I'm not even trying to say it's Pythonic. The OP's question is "how to create an list of a specific type". My answer comprehension is: "In Python you just use generic list. You don't need anything else. But if you really have to then..." You never know - maybe it's a homework and the requirement is to restrict the type of items. __No. I'm not using this in my projects.__

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It's actually [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl), Look Before You Leap, for anyone confused

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo one practical reason can be to automatically convert Python object into a different format which requires static types (ex: protobuf). If the list is empty, there is no way to deduce the type appart if the list is also statically typed.

Comment: @Conchylicultor C'm on. For that you'd need type hint on the list object at most instead of the enforcement code. This is as easy as adding a field to the object i.e. `typehint = SomeType` and using it when serializing the object. And with `protobuf` even this is not needed since the expected type is defined in `.proto` files and it's a no-brainer to use it.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo In my case, the type cannot be deduced from the `.proto` as it uses `oneof kind {BytesList FloatList Int64List}`. Otherwise, I agree that a typehint attribute do the trick.

Comment: @Conchylicultor then you either go with typehint field or convert empty list to protobuf empty array of any valid type as defined with `oneof kind {BytesList FloatList Int64List}`

Answer (score 5):

Since Python 3.5 you are able to do this:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

```
self.arrayOfGhosts: list[Ghost] = []
```

You also can import `List` and use the following code:

```
from typing import List

self.arrayOfGhosts: List[Ghost] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Lists in Python can grow as needed, they are not fixed in length like you might be used to in C or C++.

Therefore, there is no need to "initialize" a list in Python. Just create it when you need it, and then add to it as you like.

You absolutely don't need a "zeroed list" of your Ghost objects, simply do this:

```
scary_farm = []  # This is an empty list.
ghosts = []

# .. much later down in your code

mean_ghost = Ghost(scary_level=10, voice='Booooo!')
ghosts.append(mean_ghost)

casper = Ghost(scary_level=-1, voice="I'm the friendly ghost. Hee hee!")
ghosts.append(casper)

# ... later on
scary_farm.append(ghosts) # Now you have your 2-D list

for item in scary_farm:
    for ghost in item:
        print('{0.voice}'.format(ghost))
```

Note you also don't need a list of indexes when stepping through a list *or any collection* in Python. In C/C++ you might be used to:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    cout << scary_farm[i] << endl;
}
```

But this is not required in Python as collection types can be iterated over directly.

Answer (score 0):

`from typing import List` is deprecated since Python 3.9.
Now you don't need to import something, you can just use list.
Example:
`my_list: list[float] = list()`