# Creating a default constructor from another class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two classes that I created:

```
class MyBaseClass(object):

    string_a = None
    string_b = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.string_a = str()
        self.string_b = str()

class MyClass(object):

    my_strings = None

    def __init__(self):
        my_strings = List[MyBaseClass]
```

This seems to create them fine but I try to append a list in my code and the `my_strings is None` always occurs:

```
my_class = MyClass()

# Errors here since the my_class.my_strings is None still
my_class.append("heelo", "world")
```

How do I create a default `List[MyBaseClass]` that isn't None but has 0 objects in it?

Comment: Why do you expect `my_class.append` to work? `my_class` is not a list itself, it's an instance of your `MyClass` type. Unless you give it an `append` method, that call won't work. I'm very confused what you are wanting to do with `my_strings`, none of the code you show makes much sense. `List[MyBaseClass]` seems like an attempt at an annotation, rather than anything useful. At runtime, it's is like writing `list` (without calling it).

Comment: you don't need to inherit from `object`, just use `class MyBaseClass:` and `class MyClass:` (the parentheses are not needed either if there is no inheritance, also this isn't a complete [mre]

Comment: `my_strings = List` -> `self.my_strings = List`

Comment: `my_strings = List[MyBaseClass]` doesn't make any sense, that is a type alias...

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
class MyBaseClass(object):
    string_a = None
    string_b = None

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.string_a = a
        self.string_b = b


class MyClass(object):
    my_strings: List[MyBaseClass] = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_strings = []


my_class = MyClass()

my_class.my_strings.append(MyBaseClass("heelo", "world"))

print(my_class.my_strings[0].string_a)
print(my_class.my_strings[0].string_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python lists don't have a type. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160831/how-to-create-an-list-of-a-specific-type-but-empty).

A working version of your example could look like this:

```
class MyBaseClass(object):

    def __init__(self, a='', b=''):

        self.string_a = a
        self.string_b = b


class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.my_strings = list()

    def append(self, a, b):

        self.my_strings.append(MyBaseClass(a, b))


my_class = MyClass()
my_class.append("heelo", "world")
```

You were also asking about a default constructor. A simple way to achieve this is by using default arguments, as in the `MyBaseClass` constructor above.